# Почему у структур нет ссылки на объект-тип?

Tags: c#, .net, cil

Увидел, что при обращении к методу GetType() у структуры происходит boxing. Почему просто не выделяется место под ссылку на объект-тип на стеке и не инициализируется CLR?

Comment: Увидел где? Что значит "ссылка на объект тип на стеке"?

Comment: @tym32167 , в il коде метода команда box. Ну то есть под локальные переменные выделяется память на стеке потока, а ссылка на объект-тип часть значимого типа, т.е память выделяется и под нее.

Comment: Так вы приведите ваш код, дальше приведите IL инструкции, в которые ваш код превратился, укажите место в этом коде, о котором вы спрашиваете. А то получается вы где то что то сделали, какой то результат получили и задаете вопросы по вашему эксперименту, детали которого не показали.

Comment: Возможно после компиляции il боксинга не будет.